# How to retrieve the hash values in the views in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I have an action in the controller:

```
def user_detail
    @user_detail = UserDetail.find_by_id(11)
end
```

And in the view:

```
<%= @user_detail -%> // displays me like #
```

I am trying to retrieve the contents of @user_detail: actually the hash contains    `{:empid=>"11111", :prjtname=>"aaaaa", :prjtrole=>"Developer"}`

How do I display the user detail's empid and other values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since I know what question you asked earlier, I think this is the syntax you actually want to use:

```
<%= @user_detail.additional_info[:empid] %>
```

Unless of course you renamed the name of the hash :)

Another approach, if you want all the content from the hash but the keys varies from each record, you could loop through them like this:

```
<% @user_detail.additional_info.each_pair do |key, value| %>
  <p>Key: <%= key %> Value: <%= value %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

To get simple debug output like the example you posted, this will handle it:

```
<%= @user_detail.inspect %>
```

Comment: @Dogweather - the above one gives me the result as

Comment: # "11111", :prjtname=>"AAAA", :prjtrole=>"Developer"}, reporting_to: 1>  . 
               


        

        
</userdetail>

Comment: @Dogweather - how to get the individual values like the empid alone ??

Comment: To get one key's value, just use the hash as you would normally: @user_detail['empid']

Comment: @Dogweather this won't work because the keys in the hash are symbols and not strings as mentioned by you so @user_dateail['empid'] will not work instead @user_detail[:empid] might go on.

Comment: @Dogweather -  <%= @user_detail["prjtname"] %> |
           <%= @user_detail[:prjtname] %> both these doesnt displaying anything ..

Answer (score 2):

try this `<%= @user_detail.emplid %> <%= @user_detail.prjtname %>  <%= @user_detail.prjtr %>`

Comment: ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `empid' for #<UserDetail:0xb5b1b31c>) on line. is the error i am getting when i used as <%= @user_detail.emplid %>

Comment: @aruna try <%= @user_detail.id %>

Comment: <%= @user_detail.id %>  will gives the id of the row.. But i am trying to find the values of the hash whose keys are empid,prjtname ..  <%= @user_detail.empid %> throws the error..

Answer (score 1):

More of an extraction from @dln's answer

try using

```
<%= @user_detail[:emplid] %>
<%= @user_detail[:prjtname] %>
<%= @user_detail[:prjtr] %>
```

Hope this solves your prob