# Suggestion needed for keeping hash value in the table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As an extension of the question

[How to retrieve the hash values in the views in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395466/how-to-retrieve-the-hash-values-in-the-views-in-rails)

I have some doubts of keeping hash values in the table..

I have a user detail table where i am maintaining the additional details of the user in a column named additional_info in a hash format .. Will it be good in keeping like so...

As if the user scenario changes if the user wants to find all the users under a particular project  where i kept the project to which the user belongs in the hash format..

Give some suggestions..

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is to serialiaze it:

```
class FooBar < ActiveRecord::Base
# ...
  serialize :additional_info
#...
end
```

This internally uses the `YAML` serializer. You can assign any object that can be serialized using YAML.

```
foo = FooBar.first
foo.additional_info = {:foo => 'Lorem', :bar => 'ipsum'}
foo.save
foo.additional_info[:foo] # Gives 'Lorem'
```

Comment: ya i have used the same tat u have mentioned.. But is it possible to list all the users under some additional detail like users who are under some project ?? where the project details are kept in a hash in additional_info...

Comment: You will have write your own SQL query for that. But if you have to do this, it means your database design is wrong. You need to normalize and store information in more tables.

Comment: my table is like user_detail(id,user_id,additional_info(:empid:"",:prjtname: "aaa",:designation:"be")). is my structure is correct ??